# Replace multiple Strings in file

Tags: python, replace

I want to replace different MAC address notations in a file with one notation given as an argument:

```
python mac_replacer.py -m 00:1a:e8:31:71:7f -f sample.txt
```

Every MAC address that corresponds to the given one should be replaced.

> Lorem **00.1a.e8.31.71.7f** ipsum fb76.03f0.6701 dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing sed **001ae831717f** diam voluptua. **00-1a-e8-31-71-7f**At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet fb7603f06701 clita kasd gubergren **001a-e831-717f**

should turn to:

> Lorem **00:1a:e8:31:71:7f** ipsum fb76.03f0.6701 dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing sed **00:1a:e8:31:71:7f** diam voluptua. **00:1a:e8:31:71:7f**At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet fb7603f06701 clita kasd gubergren **00:1a:e8:31:71:7f**

What I have done so far is parsing the MAC address from the argument into a converter which identifies the input and outputs all the other notations I need to find them in the given text. But I am semi-failing at replacing them.

(Code shows the case that the given MAC address is in the hex notation; left out the identifier part, loads of if-statements)

```
mac = args.mac_address #In this case 00:1a:e8:31:71:7f

colon2 = mac #00:1a:e8:31:71:7f
dot2 = colon2.replace(":",".") # 00.1a.e8.31.71.7f
hyphen2 = colon2.replace(":","-") # 00-1a-e8-31-71-7f
nosymbol = colon2.replace(":","") # 001ae831717f
colon4 = ':'.join(integer[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(integer), 4)) # 001a:e831:717f 
dot4 = colon4.replace(":",".") # 001a.e831.717f
hyphen4 = colon4.replace(":","-") # 001a-e831-717f


with open(args.filename, "rt") as in_put: # File: sample.txt
    with open("out.txt", "wt") as out_put:
        for line in in_put:
            out_put.write(line.replace(nosymbol, mac))
```

This works but I would need to repeat the whole with-construct several times. Is there any better solution to this? Also I would like to write the changes back to the same file. I tried it but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Put your patterns in a list and loop through them:

```
mac = args.mac_address #In this case 00:1a:e8:31:71:7f

colon2 = mac #00:1a:e8:31:71:7f
dot2 = colon2.replace(":",".") # 00.1a.e8.31.71.7f
hyphen2 = colon2.replace(":","-") # 00-1a-e8-31-71-7f
nosymbol = colon2.replace(":","") # 001ae831717f
colon4 = "001a:e831:717f" # integer is missing used your string instead
dot4 = colon4.replace(":",".") # 001a.e831.717f
hyphen4 = colon4.replace(":","-") # 001a-e831-717f


replacethis = [ colon2 , dot2, hyphen2, nosymbol, colon4, dot4, hyphen4]  

put ="""Lorem 00.1a.e8.31.71.7f ipsum fb76.03f0.6701 dolor sit amet, 
consetetur sadipscing sed 001ae831717f diam voluptua. 
00-1a-e8-31-71-7fAt vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. 
Stet fb7603f06701 clita kasd gubergren 001a-e831-717f"""

for line in put.split("\n"):
    for n in replacethis:                 
        line = line.replace(n, mac)             
    print(line)
```

Output:

```
Lorem 00:1a:e8:31:71:7f ipsum fb76.03f0.6701 dolor sit amet, 
consetetur sadipscing sed 00:1a:e8:31:71:7f diam voluptua. 
00:1a:e8:31:71:7fAt vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. 
Stet fb7603f06701 clita kasd gubergren 00:1a:e8:31:71:7f
```

**Tested:**

your code misses `integer` and hence `colon4`, `dot4`, `hyphen4` can not be build - I used the pattern from the comment instead - and used print to screen instead file for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.sub`:

```
import re
import contextlib
@contextlib.contextmanager
def change_log(filename):
  data = open(filename).read()
  addresses = re.findall('[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]+\.\d+\.\d+\.[a-z0-9]+|[a-z0-9]+\-[a-z0-9]+\-[a-z0-9]+\-\d+\-\d+\-[a-z0-9]+|[a-z0-9]+\-[a-z0-9]+\-[a-z0-9]+', data)
  new_data = re.sub('[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]+\.\d+\.\d+\.[a-z0-9]+|[a-z0-9]+\-[a-z0-9]+\-[a-z0-9]+\-\d+\-\d+\-[a-z0-9]+|[a-z0-9]+\-[a-z0-9]+\-[a-z0-9]+', re.sub('\.', ':', addresses[0]), data)
  yield data
  f = open(filename, 'w')
  f.write(new_data)
  f.close()

with change_log('sample.txt') as f:
  print(f)
```

Output:

```
Lorem 00:1a:e8:31:71:7f ipsum fb76.03f0.6701 dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing sed 001ae831717f diam voluptua. 00:1a:e8:31:71:7fAt vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet fb7603f06701 clita kasd gubergren 00:1a:e8:31:71:7f
```